# Orchard CMS localize arbitrary text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I'm currently in the process of building a site in Orchard CMS and have come across a little stumbling block.

What would be the correct way to localize bits of arbitrary text on the site such as button labels (Back to meet the team) or direction text on a page for example (please select a distributor from the map to view the distributor details).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Anto

Comment: You can use the Orchard localize helper to display localized text in your views. The helper is simple to use: `<label>@T("My localized text")</label>`. Then you add the localized text to the po files, either in your module or in the site's po file.

Comment: aha! that worked perfectly. I knew there would be something like this from previous experience with CMS's such as Nop; just couldn't quite find it in the docs. Thanks again devqon

Comment: Sorry should have added it as an answer, I have now :) glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Orchard localize helper to display localized text in your views. The helper is simple to use: `<label>@T("My localized text")</label>`. Then you add the localized text to the po files, either in your module or in the site's po file.